# Autosize uistackview by device resolution size

Tags: ios, swift, uiimageview, storyboard, uistackview

I have a stack view on my layout, but when I try a bigger device like an iPad, the image views inside the stackview doesn't autosize:

[image]

I think I did a mistake on the constraints or stack view can't resize by the resolution ?

How can I manage my layout to have this grid format and resize the image view inside ?

Comment: What constraints did you added?

Comment: @LoVo Constraints from top and bottom

Comment: you can programmatically calculate the screen width/height and later according to these numbers to set constraints programmatically to these blocks

Comment: @iamalizade I also want to center this "grid"

Comment: @Ben no matters, you can do what you want programmatically